# How to update a DataFrame given another DataFrame with the values for update?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Zeppelin 0.6.2 and Spark 2.0.

I'm trying execute a query inside of a loop and it's not very effective.

I need to loop for each row of a dataframe, around 5000 rows and execute a query which will increment a value in another dataframe.

Here's my try at it:

```
val t2 = time
t2.registerTempTable("t2")
u.collect().foreach{ r => 
println(r(0))
val c=r(1)
val start="\""+r(2)+"\""
val end="\""+r(3)+"\""
sql("INSERT INTO TABLE t2 SELECT time, recordings + "+c+" AS recordings FROM time WHERE time >= " + start + " AND time < " + end)
}
```

I tried taking a tiny portion of the two dataframes but it is still really slow. I feel like I'm not doing this right.

Any idea how I can quickly update a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to loop for each row of a dataframe, around 5000 rows and execute a query which will increment a value in another dataframe.

I could spot `u`, `time` and `t2` tables. `t2` is to alias `time` so you can later use it in `INSERT` query. Right?

PROTIP: I'd be nice to have their schema.

Let's assume you've got a 5000-row DataFrame called `df5k`:

```
// it's a fake 5k = a mere 5 rows for the sake of simplicity
// I think `u` is your 5k table (that you unnecessarily `collect` to `foreach`)
val u = Seq(
  (0, 0, 0, 3),
  (1, 3, 4, 5),
  (2, 6, 6, 8),
  (3, 9, 9, 17)).toDF("id", "c", "start", "end")

// I think `t2` is an alias for `time` and you want to update `t2`
val time = Seq(
  (1, 10),
  (4, 40),
  (9, 90)).toDF("time", "recordings")

// this is the calculation of the new records
val new_t2 = u.join(time)
  .where('time >= 'start)
  .where('time < 'end)
  .withColumn("recordings + c", 'recordings + 'c)
  .select('time, $"recordings + c" as 'recordings)

// the following is an equivalent of INSERT INTO using Dataset API
val solution = time.union(new_t2)
```

Note: you are not updating DataFrame, but creating new DataFrame with new values.

Comment: Many thanks ! I was not even sure my question would make sense to others. I modified my code using your input and I got a message saying that I should add spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true) to do this and at that moment I realized that crossjoin was the solution I needed and not a foreach row.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT built every day so we're indeed using different versions of Spark, but I didn't know there could've been so important changes between 2.x releases. What exactly is your Spark version? Use `spark.version` to find it out. You definitely should stick to Spark SQL's way of computing "things". Please accept my answer at your earliest convenience iff it addressed your use case. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, could you please add the most current version of the code to the question (so others could benefit from your changes too)? I and other SOers would appreciate very much. I could also help you with the use of `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true)`. Thanks!